# Defined variable is not defined

Tags: python, variables, import, nameerror

I am working on a text adventure to learn Python. I have got to where I am trying to create a battle engine and running into a problem where the error is saying that I have not defined a variable that is indeed defined. Attached is the battle engine code and then I will post the errors I am getting:

```
import random
import time
import sys

player_health = 100
enemy_health = random.randint(50,120)

def monster_damage():
    global player_health
    global enemy_health
    mon_dmg = random.randint(5, 25)
    enemy_health -= mon_dmg
    print('You hit the beast for ' + str(mon_dmg) + ' damage! Which brings its health to ' + str(enemy_health))
    if enemy_health < 0:
        print('You have vanquished the beast and saved our Chimichongas')
        win == True
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        player_dmg()

def player_dmg():
    global player_health
    global enemy_health
    pla_dmg = random.randint(5, 15)
    player_health -= pla_dmg
    print(
        'The beast strikes out for ' + str(pla_dmg) + ' damage to you. This leaves you with ' + str(player_health))
    if player_health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
        player_turn()
    elif player_health <= 0:
        print('The beast has vanquished you!')
        win == False
        time.sleep(10)
        sys.exit()

def run_away():
    run_chance = random.randint(1, 10)
    if run_chance > 5:
        print('You escape the beast!')
        time.sleep(10)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('You try to run and fail!')
        player_dmg()

def player_turn():
    print('Your Turn:')
    print('Your Health: ' + str(player_health) + ' Monsters Health: ' + str(enemy_health))
    print('What is your next action?')
    print('Please Select 1 to attack or 2 to run.')
    action = int(input())

    if action == 1:
        monster_damage()
    elif action == 2:
        run_away()

def battle_start():
    player_turn()

battle_start()
```

And the errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rhood/Documents/python_files/game/rps_exp.py", line 15, in <module>
    game()
  File "C:\Users\rhood\Documents\python_files\game\main_game.py", line 25, in game
battle()
  File "C:\Users\rhood\Documents\python_files\game\battle.py", line 63, in battle
    battle_start()
  File "C:\Users\rhood\Documents\python_files\game\battle.py", line 61, in battle_start
player_turn()
  File "C:\Users\rhood\Documents\python_files\game\battle.py", line 56, in player_turn
monster_damage()
  File "C:\Users\rhood\Documents\python_files\game\battle.py", line 14, in monster_damage
    enemy_health -= mon_dmg
NameError: name 'enemy_health' is not defined
```

Comment: You didn't add `global enemy_health` in `player_turn` function

Comment: *"the error is saying that I have not defined a variable that is indeed defined"* - one of you's wrong, and I'm not betting against the interpreter.

Comment: After importing random the code seems to run. Where and how does the error occur?

Comment: After `import sys` and `import random` this code runs perfectly, at least until `win` needs to be evaluated at the end of the fight.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is import the `sys`, `random`, and `time` modules and define the variable `win`.

Comment: I have them imported but I did not copy them when putting in the code, I just saw that I am sorry, it could be the IDE that I am running in, it is Pycharms. I will try it later tonight from another system and see if it will run